# DiscortJS bot send a message back on the channel mentioning a specific user

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, mention

I have build this message on js. And i want to add a condition if you tag an user the bot to add the message + tag that person otherwise just to send a normal message.

The issue that I have is what is the right variable for user_mention. I found different ways, but couldn't make it to work.

```
DiscordClient.on('message', message => {
  const msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
  const mention = message.mentions.users;

  if (msg === "yubnub") {
    if (mention == null){
      message.channel.send('YUB NUB!! YUB NUB!! Grrrrr!!');
    } else {
      message.channel.send('YUB NUB!! YUB NUB!! Grrrrr!! ' + ${@user_mention})
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `mention` is an array of [users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User). So you can do:

```js
for (const user of mention) {
    message.channel.send('YUB NUB!! YUB NUB!! Grrrrr!! @' + user.username)
}
```

Comment: Not talking about the JS condition. Talking about how i can get the @user_mention. I need the right variable/paramater. i couldn't manage to find the right one.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is wrong.  @Creator You should never mark wrong answers as right.  That will result in someone finding the wrong answer later and trying to use it.  The right answer is in fact your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @boris and @Adrian. The final code looks like this:

```
if (msg.startsWith("yubjub")) {
const mention = message.mentions.members;

if (mention.size === 0){

  message.channel.send('YUB NUB!! YUB NUB!! Grrrrr!!);

} else {
    const mentionUser = mention.first().user;

    message.channel.send('YUB NUB!! YUB NUB!! Stab Stab Stab <@' + mentionUser.id + '> !!');

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```js
const mention = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Source: https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/command-with-arguments#grabbing-mentions